# MultiPartParser not working in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am using MultiPartParser and Formparser in drf, and using multipart/form-data html form for uploading a image  but it doesn't seem to be working for me. i am getting this error 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte. You passed in '\x89PNG\r\n' ()
using request.data['image'] for retrieving my uploaded image 
Any kind of help would be appreciated

Comment: The Django / Django REST framework and Python versions could help as well as the full traceback.